# ReactJS - Dropdown events cant be triggered because Input looses focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need a search box in React that opens a dropdown as soon as an entry is made. The dropdown should contain buttons that can trigger an event.

The problem is that the dropdown has to disappear as soon as another input box is used in the application.

I could also implement this, but now I have the problem that the event of the button in question is not triggered because the focus of the input field is lost beforehand as soon as I press the button. As a result, the dropdown disappears and the event is never triggered.

This is roughly my Searchbox Component:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Dropdown from './Dropdown';

function Search(props) {

    const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
    
    const inputHandler = (params) => {
        if (params.length > 0)
            props.apiCall(params);
    }
    
    const buttonHandler = (id) => {
        console.log(id);
    }
    
    return (
        <>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Suchen.."
                onChange={(event) => inputHandler(event.target.value)}
                onFocus={() => setFocused(true)}
                onBlur={() => setFocused(false)} // Problem area
            />
            {
                focused === true && props.apiData.length > 0 ?
                    props.apiData.map((mappedData, key) => {
                        return (
                            <Dropdown
                                key={key}
                                id={mappedData.id}
                                name={mappedData.name}
                                /*
                                  even more Data
                                */
                                buttonHandler={buttonHandler}
                            />
                        )
                    })
                    : null
            }
        </>
    )

}

export default Search;
```

This is my Dropdown Component:

```js
import React from 'react';

function Dropdown(props) {

    return (
        <ul key={props.id}>
            <li>{props.name}</li>
            <li>even more data</li>
            <li>
                <input
                    type="button"
                    value="Select"
                    onClick={() => {
                        props.buttonHandler(props.id)
                    }}
                />
            </li>
        </ul>
    )

}

export default Dropdown;
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue blur event in Search Component can be handled with delay.

```
function Search(props) {
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);

  const inputHandler = (params) => {
    if (params.length > 0) props.apiCall(params);
  };

  const buttonHandler = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Suchen.."
        onChange={(event) => inputHandler(event.target.value)}
        onFocus={() => setFocused(true)}
-       onBlur={() => setFocused(false)} // Problem area --> remove this line
+       onBlur={() => setTimeout(()=> setFocused(false),500)} // ---> delay added 
      />
      {focused === true && props.apiData.length > 0
        ? props.apiData.map((mappedData, key) => {
            return (
              <Dropdown
                key={key}
                id={mappedData.id}
                name={mappedData.name}
                /*
                                  even more Data
                                */
                buttonHandler={buttonHandler}
              />
            );
          })
        : null}
    </>
  );
}
```